# Changing og:title Facebook relative to url parameter

Tags: php, facebook, get, request

I want to replace the `og:title` contents, but Facebook cannot read my script.
I 've tried the tool debuger but `$_REQUEST['id']` or `$_GET['id']` is empty.

I want to show the `$_REQUEST['id']` but which appears still *domain.com*.

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $ogTitle = 'domain.com';
}else{
    $ogTitle = $_REQUEST['id']
};
<meta property='og:title' content='<?php echo $ogTitle ?>'>
```

Comment: What is the 'id' parameter ?

Comment: @DavidAnsermot : ' id ' that I send is encrypted ,
I sent through the link domain.com/kuis/PVVUTTNhMDcyNzczYjA5Yw==
, 
' id ' is in its ' PVVUTTNhMDcyNzczYjA5Yw == '

but facebook read that ' id ' empty , whereas in my website appear $ _REQUEST [ ' id ' ] his

Comment: But the 'id' field is not an url parameter as it is. Your website AND Facebook can't guess that it's a parameter. You should have a link to your site with the parameter in the url or as a post.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot : I Already Tried like this http://www.domain.com/index.php?module=kuis&id=PVVUTTNhMDcyNzczYjA5Yw== , but the result is still the same , my id is not readable , but on my website script path

Comment: @DavidAnsermot : Can you give an example to replace og : title matches the name of the website content

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code.

It should be :

```
    $ogTitle = 'domain.com';
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) {
        $ogTitle = $_GET['id'];
    }
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $ogTitle; ?>">
```

The **;** was not at the right place.

Comment: no my script it's don't have error,
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $ogTitle = 'domain.com';
}else{
    $ogTitle = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
?>
<meta property='og:title' content='<?php echo $ogTitle ?>'>

Comment: Yeah so you made mistakes in the question post. I've updated answer with working code for me.

Comment: sorry sir , still can not , this my address , you try to share what his website title changed. http://adakuis.com/kuis/PVVUTTI2NmEyZTJlMzc5Yw==      .on its website script path , og : title changed . But when share on facebook who remain adaKuis.com not read Kuis - algoritma

Comment: So it seems to be your rewrite code not working right.

Comment: there is a problem with my .htacess ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that your website can't extract the parameter from the Facebook request.

Comment: but on my website og : title successfully changed in accordance with the content name

Comment: Another thing is that Facebook have a cache for external urls. You should wait and check again in some hours. Or find (I don't remember where) the link to flush cache of your Facebook account

Comment: okay thankyou for you answer sir, I wait for other answers Friend

Answer (score 0):

You said (in comments) that you are trying to share the URL `http://adakuis.com/kuis/PVVUTTI2NmEyZTJlMzc5Yw==` – but that says in its meta data, that the *actual* address of the Open Graph object was your index page,

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://adakuis.com/" />
```

– that value of course has to be `http://adakuis.com/kuis/PVVUTTI2NmEyZTJlMzc5Yw==` as well, otherwise Facebook will go look for the meta data to use under `http://adakuis.com/`.